# Angular RouteReuseStrategy with aux routes (Reuse only the main part)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

Asume you have a main route and an aux route.
The aux route represents a part of the app, where details can be viewed.
So most of the time the aux-route-part is not activated/empty.
When a user clicks on the detail-button in the main part, the aux-route is being set and the detail component appears.

The problem is: Everytime the aux route is set, the main part also gets reloaded, which -for me- is an undesired behaviour. I mean, the main route doesn't change. Why should it get reloaded?

As far as I can tell it's because of the default RouteReuseStrategy (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/51955bf6205272b1d2b98ff5b6dafd3823039ae2/packages/router/src/route_reuse_strategy.ts#L65). As soon as the `routeConfig` changes -which is what happens when an aux route gets set- the method `shouldReuseRoute` returns `false` and therefore the components don't get reused.

My attempt to solve this was to create a custom RouteReuseStrategy where I would compare only the main route in `shouldReuseRoute`. So, if the user clicks on the detail button and only the aux route gets set and the main route stays the same, `shouldReuseRoute` returns `true`. But this leads to not loading the aux-part of the app at all. Seems like all components of all `router-outlets` get reused and therefore the detail component doesn't get loaded because it wasn't there before. Makes sense to me...

Right now I don't have any idea how to solve this? Can anyone help me? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Share your router config and navigation details.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem here...

Comment: Unfortunately not. I still have to live with this behavior.